# DefaultConfigSourceProvider not a subtype when deploying EAR artifact in Jboss 7

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss, deltaspike

When we create a configuration in IntelliJ to deploy an ear artifact and deploy it, it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
09:01:00,399 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment tenantmgmt-ear.ear
09:01:00,697 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."tenantmgmt-ear.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."tenantmgmt-ear.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.config.ConfigSourceProvider: Provider org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.DefaultConfigSourceProvider not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ServiceUtils.loadServiceImplementations(ServiceUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ServiceUtils.loadServiceImplementations(ServiceUtils.java:46)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.resolveConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:505)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:483)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getPropertyValue(ConfigResolver.java:352)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getPropertyValue(ConfigResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.resolveProjectStage(ProjectStageProducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.initProjectStage(ProjectStageProducer.java:169)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.lazyInit(ProjectStageProducer.java:139)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.getInstance(ProjectStageProducer.java:118)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.performProjectStageDependentCleanup(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.isActivated(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.DeltaSpikeContextExtension.init(DeltaSpikeContextExtension.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:163)
    ... 14 more

    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:344)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:346)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:73)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:171)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.deltaspike.core.spi.config.ConfigSourceProvider: Provider org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.DefaultConfigSourceProvider not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:369)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ServiceUtils.loadServiceImplementations(ServiceUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ServiceUtils.loadServiceImplementations(ServiceUtils.java:46)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.resolveConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:505)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getConfigSources(ConfigResolver.java:483)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getPropertyValue(ConfigResolver.java:352)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.ConfigResolver.getPropertyValue(ConfigResolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.resolveProjectStage(ProjectStageProducer.java:150)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.initProjectStage(ProjectStageProducer.java:169)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.lazyInit(ProjectStageProducer.java:139)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer.getInstance(ProjectStageProducer.java:118)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.performProjectStageDependentCleanup(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:90)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ClassDeactivationUtils.isActivated(ClassDeactivationUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.DeltaSpikeContextExtension.init(DeltaSpikeContextExtension.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:163)
    ... 14 more

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:335)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more

09:01:01,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "tenantmgmt-ear.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"tenantmgmt-ear.ear\".WeldService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"tenantmgmt-ear.ear\".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection...
```

However when we build the artifact in Maven and copy it manually to the deployment folder of the application server, the problem does not occur. We're not sure if the issue is relates to Deltaspike.

It's also something that does not happen to everyone in the company, so it's something weird.

Any input would be appreciated.